# Ionic Capacitor - missing build command

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, capacitor

I have two machines. Each of them has same Ionic project from same git repo. the first one has missing `capacitor build` option (see the pictures)

Machines have different ionic version (6.12.0 vs 5.4.16) How can I add 'build' functionality to capacitor in computer 1?

Computer 1:
[image]

Computer 2:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ionic capacitor build` was introduced in `@ionic/cli` version **6.6.0** (see their [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/develop/packages/%40ionic/cli/CHANGELOG.md#660-2020-04-14))

so the solution for Computer 1 is to upgrade `@ionic/cli` at least to that version.